# Rational Requisite Pro

Tags: ibm-rational

My company wants to use `Rational Requisite Pro` to manage their requirement documents, and they want me to come up with a plan.

I need to know where can I go to start this process?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by asking what problem the company expects Requisite Pro to solve for them. More often than not companies select a tool as a band-aid for a process that's fundamentally broken to begin with. If an organization doesn't fix the real problem then they'll end up just spending a bunch of money and get little value out of it.

My 2 cents.

Brandon

Comment: My company is big, any idea how to collect the infomartion about the problem they might be having with the current requirement collection software.

Comment: do you think, i can use the Rational reqpro by itself.

Comment: I'd start with the project stakeholders. If your company is really large, I wouldn't be surprised if they think they gain some sort of organizational efficiency by standardizing on a tool (which isn't necessarily true). Of course I've also been around organizations where the primary reason for using a tool is because the exec that paid the 250K for it doesn't want to admit it was a mistake. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like downloading the trial and looking at the docs would be a good place to start:

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/reqpro/

Unless some eejit manager has already made the decision, I'd wonder if a survey of tools would be a good idea.  Sometimes an open source tool can be better than a licensed product.  For example, Subversion is the hands-down winner over ClearCase, the Rational source code management system.  Perhaps that will be the case here as well.  You owe it to yourself and your company to know who leads in this space and what open source alternatives there are:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osrmt/

Comment: my company already got the rational suite and got to come up with some migration plan.

Comment: So what's to plan?  Learn how to use it.

Comment: my Project lead told me that i have to come up with some plan, how that rational tool is going to help them. I am thinking about collecting the problem, what they face now. but no idea how to do it. i cant talk to all the programmer and DBA's and everyone. can you advice me something on this.( collecting what problem they are facing now). So that i can work on those issues and work towards it.